# Required field on angular form with Formaway and formbuilder

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, required, form-control

I search desperately looking for a few hours to put a simple required field div using an ngif on my various form controls. Here is my code:
Typescript:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators,FormArray, FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chargement-du-questionnaire',
  templateUrl: './chargement-du-questionnaire.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chargement-du-questionnaire.component.css']
})
export class ChargementDuQuestionnaireComponent {
  i: number = 0;
  errorMessage: string="";

  credit: FormGroup= new FormGroup({ 
typeDePret: new FormControl(''),
montantDuPret: new FormControl(''), 
tauxDuPret: new FormControl(''),
dureeDuPret: new FormControl(''),
dontDiffere: new FormControl(''), });


  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
      profileForm = this.fb.group({
      credit: this.fb.group({
        typeDePret: [''],
        montantDuPret: [Validators.required,Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$')],
        tauxDuPret: [''],
        dureeDuPret: [''],
        dontDiffere: [''],
        
      }),
      aliases: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.control('')
      ])
    });
    ngOnInit() {
      this.credit = new FormGroup({ 
        typeDePret: new FormControl(''),
        montantDuPret: new FormControl(Validators.required), 
        tauxDuPret: new FormControl(''),
        dureeDuPret: new FormControl(''),
        dontDiffere: new FormControl(''), });}
get montantDuPret() { return this.credit.get('montantDuPret')! }



    get aliasArray() {
      return this.profileForm.get('aliases') as FormArray;
    }
    
    addAlias() {
      if (this.aliasArray.length === 3) {
        this.errorMessage="Limiter à 3 prêts";
        setTimeout(() => {
          window.scrollTo({ top: document.body.scrollHeight, behavior: 'smooth' });
        }, 10);
      } else {
        this.errorMessage = "";
        this.aliasArray.push(this.fb.control(''));
        setTimeout(() => {
          window.scrollTo({ top: document.body.scrollHeight, behavior: 'smooth' });
        }, 10);
      }
    }
    removeAlias(index: number) {
      if (this.aliasArray.length === 3) {
        this.errorMessage="";
      }
      this.aliasArray.removeAt(index);
    }
    
  }
```

and html:

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm"class="needs-validation" novalidate>
        <div formArrayName="aliases">
          <div class="form" *ngFor="let alias of aliasArray.controls; let i=index">
           <p> Pret n°{{i+1}}</p> 
           <div>
            <label for="typeDePret-{{ i}}">Type de prêt:</label><br>
          <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example"id="typeDePret-{{ i }}" [formControlName]="i">
            <option value="1">Prêt classique (amortissable)</option>
            <option value="2">In fine</option>
            <option value="3">Prêt à taux Zéro</option>
            <option value="4">Prêt relais</option>
          </select> 
        </div>


            <label for="montantDuPret-{{i}}">Montant du prêt</label><br>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <input id="montantDuPret-{{i}}" type="text" [formControlName]="i" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)"formControlName="montantDuPret" id="montantDuPret"required>
              <span class="input-group-text">.00 €</span> 
              <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="montantDuPret.invalid && montantDuPret.touched">
                <div *ngIf="montantDuPret.errors?.['required']">
                  Svp entrer le montant de votre pret.

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
                    
            <label for="tauxDuPret-{{i}}">Taux du prêt</label><br>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <input id="tauxDuPret-{{i}}" type="text" [formControlName]="i" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)"formControlName="tauxDuPret" id="tauxDuPret"required>
              <span class="input-group-text">%</span>  
            </div>
            <label for="dureeDuPret-{{i}}">Durée totale</label><br>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <input id="dureeDuPret-{{i}}" type="text" [formControlName]="i" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)"formControlName="dureeDuPret" id="dureeDuPret"required>
              <span class="input-group-text">an(s)</span>
              <input id="dureeDuPret-{{i}}" type="text" [formControlName]="i" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)"formControlName="dureeDuPret" id="dureeDuPret"required>
              <span class="input-group-text">mois</span>   
            </div>
            <label for="dontDiffere-{{i}}">Dont différé</label><br>
            <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example"id="dontDiffere{{i}}" [formControlName]="i">
              <option value="1">1 mois</option>
              <option value="2">2 mois</option>
              <option value="3">3 mois</option>
              <option value="4">4 mois</option>
              <option value="5">5 mois</option>
              <option value="6">6 mois</option>
              <option value="7">7 mois</option>
              <option value="8">8 mois</option>
              <option value="9">9 mois</option>
              <option value="10">10 mois</option>
              <option value="11">11 mois</option>
              <option value="12">12 mois</option>
              <option value="13">13 mois</option>
              <option value="14">14 mois</option>
              <option value="15">15 mois</option>
              <option value="16">16 mois</option>
              <option value="17">17 mois</option>
              <option value="18">18 mois</option>
              <option value="19">19 mois</option>
              <option value="20">20 mois</option>
              <option value="21">21 mois</option>
              <option value="22">22 mois</option>
              <option value="23">23 mois</option>
              <option value="24">24 mois</option>
            </select> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="error"*ngIf="errorMessage">{{errorMessage}}</div>
        <button (click)="removeAlias(i)">Remove Alias</button>
        <button type="button" (click)="addAlias()">+ Add another alias</button>
        
      </form>
```

I tried the methods described on the angular site but I have no rendering.. no div is created if the field is not filled.

I am focus on the "montantDuPret" formcontrol to do my tests, telling myself that if it works with one formcontrol the solution will be the same for the other formcontrols.

Answer (score 0):

Your `montantDuPret` is point to `this.credit.get('montantDuPret')` which is not what you expected.

Change the condition to code below and it will good to go.

```
    <div class="invalid-feedback"
      *ngIf="aliasArray.at(i).invalid && aliasArray.at(i).touched">
      <div *ngIf="aliasArray.at(i).hasError('required')">
        Svp entrer le montant de votre pret.
      </div>
    </div>
```

Reference: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tucybr?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Hello, indeed by inserting your code it makes the desired div appear but on the whole of the formcontrols there would be a solution to apply it only on a formcontrol without impacting the rest of the fields?

Comment: Did you mean specific index of `aliasArray`?

Comment: exactly for each form-control so as not to influence the other form-controls